# Datatables exportar para Excel e formatar uma coluna texto como moeda (contábil)

Tags: jquery, jquery-datatables

Estou tentando converter uma coluna numérica `8.5` em moeda contábil (**R$ 8,50**) quando utilizo exportar `Excel` do `jQuery Datatable`, mas não obtive sucesso.

Minha coluna está assim:

```
{
        "data": "Valor2", "orderable": true, "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                var valor = full.Valor.replace(',', '.');
                return parseFloat(valor);;
        }
},
```

Comment: Quando você fazer o replace, ele gera um erro, ou simplesmente não fica no formato que você quer?

Comment: Ele vai para o excel como formato "Geral", então quando utilizo a função soma, ele não consegue somar. Queria exportar com formato contábil

Comment: Porque você colocou um código, no qual você usa replace, este replace funciona? Ou esta modificação não funciona?

Comment: Esse código que coloquei do replace seria para converter o texto 8,5 por exemplo em 8.5, sendo possível assim, transformar o texto em float. O que eu queria agora era transformar esse float em moeada quando gerar o excel.

Answer (score -1):

Para que ele seja reconhecido como moeda você coloca ao parâmetro `type` com o valor `currency`

```
{
    "data": "Valor2", "orderable": true, "type": "currency"
},
```

> Esse plug-in fornecerá classificação numérica para colunas de moedas
>   (detectadas automaticamente com o plug-in de detecção do tipo de moeda
>   ou definidas manualmente), levando em consideração o símbolo monetário
>   ($ ou £ por padrão).
>
> O DataTables 1.10+ possui habilidades de classificação de moeda
>   embutidas e será detectado automaticamente. Como tal, esse plug-in é
>   marcado como obsoleto, mas pode ser útil ao trabalhar com versões
>   antigas do DataTables.

[Documentação](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/currency)

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou pra mim.

Comment: Você viu isso? a = (a==="-") ? 0 : a.replace( /[^\d\-\.]/g, "" );
        return parseFloat( a ); na documentação?

Comment: sim, eu vi.... fiz exatamente como mostra na documentação, porém no excel continua como texto

Comment: já tentou deletar o arquivo para ver se ele esta criando um novo?

Comment: sim, infelizmente desisti do datatable e resolvi usar uma lib pra gerar o excel, mas obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score -1):

Supondo que os números no json de origem venham formatados em português;
Por exemplo:

```
Salary:  162700,00
```

Foi utilizada uma rotina (fnTextoNumericoParaFloat) para fazer substituição de:

- pontos "." por espaço vazio ""
- virgulas "," por ponto "."

Para forçar o formato americano dos dados da tabela na hora de exportar para o Excel.

No meu caso, os valores foram salvos corretamente como número;

```
<script>

    function fnTextoNumericoParaFloat (sNumeroTexto, vErro) {
        var resultado = 0;
        try {
            var aux = "";
            var sFator = "";
            var fator = sNumeroTexto;
            sFator = fator.toString();
            try {
                aux = sFator;
                aux = fnReplaceAll_Aux(aux, ".", "");
                aux = fnReplaceAll_Aux(aux, ",", ".");
            } catch (error) { aux = vErro; }
            if (!$.isNumeric(aux)) { aux = vErro; }
            resultado = parseFloat(aux);
        }
        catch (error) { resultado = vErro; }
        return resultado;
    }

    function fnReplaceAll_Aux  (str, de, para) {
        str = str || ''
        var pos = str.indexOf(de);
        while (pos > -1) {
            str = str.replace(de, para);
            pos = str.indexOf(de);
        }
        return (str);
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var buttonCommon = {
            exportOptions: {
                format: {
                    body: function ( data, row, column, node ) {                                                                         
                        var valor = data; 
                        if (column === 5){                             
                            valor =fnTextoNumericoParaFloat(data,'N/D');
                            //console.log(data + ' : ' + valor);   
                        }
                        return valor ;
                        //return valor column === 5 ? data.replace( data.replace( /[.]/g, '' ), '' ): data;  
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        $('#example').DataTable( {
            ajax: 'dados.json',
            columns: [
                { data: 'name' },
                { data: 'position' },
                { data: 'office' },
                { data: 'extn' },
                { data: 'start_date' },
                { data: 'salary' }
            ],
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                $.extend( true, {}, buttonCommon, {
                    extend: 'copyHtml5'
                } ),
                $.extend( true, {}, buttonCommon, {
                    extend: 'excelHtml5'
                } ),
                $.extend( true, {}, buttonCommon, {
                    extend: 'pdfHtml5'
                } )
            ]
        } );
    } );
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Sei que o post é antigo mas como não vi nenhuma resposta que considero correta, aqui deixo minha visão.
Pelo oque entendi vc deseja pegar o formato de "8.50" e passar para "R$8,50", e depois exportar a tabela para Excel. Vamos por parte então:

#### 1) Passando de  "8.50" para  "R$8,50"

Esse tipo de procedimento deve ser feito usando a propriedade do propio DataTable 'columnDefs' e não 'forçando' através de uma renderização externa pois caso contrario vc não vai conseguir por exemplo mandar o Data table fazer a soma dos valores ou exportar para excel ou pdf com a mascara correta.
No seu código procure a propriedade 'columnDefs', caso não tenha criado pode criar, vai ficar tipo assim

```
    -- ...codigo anterior do DataTable---
    
    pageLength: 50,
    responsive:true,
    data: dataSet,
    columnDefs: [ 
                { "width": "7%", "targets": 0 }, //defini manualmente o tamanho da coluna
                { "width": "5%", "targets": 1 }, //defini manualmente o tamanho da coluna
                { "width": "5%", "targets": 2 }, //defini manualmente o tamanho da coluna
                { "width": "7%", "targets": 3 }, //defini manualmente o tamanho da coluna
                { "width": "7%", "targets": 4 }, //defini manualmente o tamanho da coluna
                {"render": function(data){       //responsavel por 'renderizar' a coluna que vc deseja aplicando o filtro R$
        return parseFloat(data).toLocaleString('pt-br',{style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL'});
        },"targets": 4 
      }
      ],    
      columns: [
               { title: "Tipo" },
               { title: "NºDoc" },
               { title: "Pedido" },
               { title: "Emissão" },
               { title: "Valor" }            
               ] 

--.... resto do código do seu DataTable ....--
```

Repare que a parte responsavel por aplicar o filtro fica dentro da propriedade 'columnDefs', 'render'.

```
{"render": function(data){       //responsavel por 'renderizar' a coluna que vc deseja aplicando o filtro R$
        return parseFloat(data).toLocaleString('pt-br',{style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL'});
        },"targets": 4 
      }
```

Aqui vc aplica corretamente a mascara e usa o comando 'targets' para apontar para qual coluna vc deseja estar aplicando

*obs:*Caso vc quisesse aplicar essa formatação para várias colunas bastaria vc colocar as colunas q deseja em array, tipo assim

```
   {"render": function(data){       //responsavel por 'renderizar' a coluna que vc deseja aplicando o filtro R$
            return parseFloat(data).toLocaleString('pt-br',{style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL'});
            },"targets": [4,5,8] 
          }
```

*Lembrando q a primeira coluna vc conta 0, pois estamos trabalhando com array aqui*

#### 2)botão de exportação Execel

Eu não sei como foi feito o botão de exportação... porém eu faço da seguinte maneira:

```
    --- ... código do dataTable ...--
columns: [
         { title: "Tipo" },
         { title: "NºDoc" },
         { title: "Pedido" },
         { title: "Emissão" },
         { title: "Valor" }            
         ],
         dom: 'Bfrtip',
         altEditor: true,
         buttons: [
                    {
                     text: 'EXCEL',
                     extend: 'excel',
                     exportOptions: {
                       modifier: {
                       page: 'current'
                       }
                      }
                     },
                   ]

-- ...resto do código do DataTable...---
```

E por fim mais não menos importante, lembre-se q vc dever importar as bibliotecas pertinentes caso não tenha, caso resolva fazer isso via cdn vai fica assim:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.1/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css"/> <!--  dataTables.css buttons -->
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script> <!--  dataTables.js buttons -->   
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script> <!--  dataTables.html5 -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script> <!--  dataTables.pdf maker -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script> <!--  dataTables.font maker -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script> <!--  dataTables.xlsx -->
```

Prontinho!! parece muito mas não é. Com isso vc aplicou a mascara de dinheiro como manda a documentação e fica livre para manipular os valores da coluna sem se preocupar com isso.